# Can't configure credentials WCF with basic realm?

Tags: c#, authentication, wcf

I have added a Connected Reference in Visual Studio 2019. It consumed a https endpoint, and created all binding information needed into a `reference.cs` file.

It didn't generate any `App.config` file, so I suspected what I needed was bundled into the `reference.cs` file. Indeed, looking into it, it mostly was.

So I tried creating a client, specify client credentials in two ways, as you can see, but still, doesn't matter how I specify it, I get an exception when calling this code below.

```
        public async Task SendFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName, Guid machineKey)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting file sending to Manager 1.");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Sending file {fileName} from Machine {machineKey}");
            try
            {
                var client = new FileTransferClient(FileTransferClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer, _options.FileTransferEndPoint)
                {
                    ClientCredentials =
                    {
                        UserName =
                        {
                            UserName = _options.FileTransferUsername,
                            Password = _options.FileTransferPassword
                        }
                    }
                };

                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _options.FileTransferUsername;
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _options.FileTransferPassword;

                using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
                {

                }

                await client.UploadAsync(new FileUploadMessage
                {
                    // Assume that this is enough. Can't really supply file length...
                    FileInfo = new FileTransferInfo
                    {
                        TransferId = new Guid(),
                        MachineUUID = machineKey.ToString(),
                        Name = fileName
                    },

                    TransferStream = fileStream
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("An unexpected exception occurred while sending file to Manager 1G.", e);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("File sending finished.");
        }
```

The exception is `"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm'."`

I have compared to similar APIs that use the beforementioned `App.config`, and have edited the `reference.cs` to match the security I think it should have.

Specifically, I've added the security related lines here:

```
       private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
       {
           if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer))
           {
               System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
               result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
               result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
               result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
               result.AllowCookies = true;
               result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
               result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
               result.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
               return result;
           }
           if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding_IFileTransfer))
           {
               System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
               System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
               result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
               System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
               httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
               httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
               httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
               result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
               return result;
           }
           throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
       }
```

What I found dumbfounding, was that with embedding in the constructor calling setting the ClientCredentials, they were not in any way populated when I inspected the `client` with a debug session attached. Hence I tried to set it afterwards specifically.

But either way, the end result is the same, get the same error.

How can I resolve that error in Code?

I can in theory try to add an `App.config` and do it there, but I don't know the Contract. And I am not sure what to look for in the generated `reference.cs` to identify it. So I'd prefer to learn to do this by Code, as the Contract is already in place there, and I can supply the endpoint via the `_options`, so it should be able to configure for different environments by that.

Comment: please edit your question and provide code, error messages and other _text-based_ information as ***text***, not as screenshot. thank you.

Comment: Changed from pictures to text based information as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had indeed password and username exchanged, so fixing that helped me get past of this issue.